# Is there any reason to manually `return` in a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, oop, compiler-construction, return, new-operator

Typically, in a constructor function, the object that is bound to `this` within the function is returned by it when it is called with the `new` prefix.  But I would imagine that it's also possible (I think I even read this in crockford's book) to manually return your own value.  Are there any places where such a practice is useful?

Comment: You can only return your own value if it's an Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you return a value type from the constructor, you'll get different behavior depending on if `new` was used.  That's how `String` works.  Look at this object in your JavaScript console:

```
{
    s: String("abc"),
    S: new String("abc")
}
```

Little `s` contains a string value, but big `S` contains a string Object.  A subtle difference, perhaps.

You could go way beyond that and use the same function for different purposes:

```
function Foo() {
    return "abc";
}
Foo.prototype.DoSomething = function () {
    // something completely unrelated to "abc"
};
var a = Foo();      // The string "abc".  Does not have a DoSomething() method.
var b = new Foo();  // An Object with a DoSomething() method.  Doesn't know about "abc".
```

Depending on whether `new` was used, you'd get back something completely different.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to implement a singleton pattern this could be used, by making sure that after the first time the object is constructed you never construct another object - instead returning the first constructed object.

i.e.

```
if(!TheClass.singleton) TheClass.singleton = this;
return TheClass.singleton
```

Comment: Not really: The question was about using a constructor with the `new` keyword. If this code was inside a constructor `Foo`, the only effect is that `TheClass.singleton` will equal to the very first instance created using `new Foo()`. However, your code implies that subsequently calling `var foo2 = new Foo()` will return the singleton, and that's definitely not true.

Comment: Um. If that's definitely not true, then isn't the whole premise of the question incorrect? Or is there an error in my code?

Comment: @meetamit: Test it. Though I think `if(!TheClass.singleton)` was intended.

Comment: Yeah, I stand corrected, IN A BIG WAY (I tried it too: http://jsfiddle.net/JWYeg/1/). Sorry to have used the word "definitely". This is messing with my world in a big way, though. For years and years I was living under the impression that this would never work. Could there have been an older version of JavaScript where this was not the case?

Comment: @meetamit Yeah, Javascript has done that to me many a time. If you just assume that you can do absolutely anything at any time you're not far off... Not sure about old versions though - that may be true.

Comment: @meetamit If you're interested, I posted a question regarding the version over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485455/what-version-of-javascript-introduced-arbitrary-constructor-return

Answer (score 3):

A constructor (i.e. a function called with `new`) always returns an object, which is `this` is the default. There are cases where you might protect against a call without `new` using say:

```
function Foo(arg) {
  if ( !(this instanceof Foo) ) {
    return new Foo(arg);
  }
  this.blah = arg;
}
```

So you return a different object to the function's `this`, but it still returns an instance of itself.

Comment: This might fail if the prototype of `Foo` contained `Foo`, since then `this` would refer to an already-existing `Foo` object, but I'm not sure what reason there would be for setting up that situation in the first place...

Comment: Actually, I just realized that that could be quite a desirable outcome - it essentially makes calling `someFoo.Foo(arg)` a reinitialization of the object, which is a very neat code reuse tool...

Comment: Cool hack, and I'm sure crockford would approve, but anyone reading this should check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13485025/1597180) answer as well.

Comment: @Jeff—saying `This might fail if the prototype of Foo contained Foo` doesn't make sense, unless you mean if `Foo` was called as a method of an instance (i.e. `foo.Foo()`). I don't use this method, if a constructor isn't called with `new` when it should be, the code should fail testing. It's just an example of a reason to return some other object.

Comment: I know, I was pointing out exactly that case (`foo.Foo()`). It wasn't a criticism of the method, just a note for anyone using this technique that there is a situation where the method is called without the `new` keyword which may then behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, think of it like this.

```
item = function(id){
  if(alreadytaken(id)){
    return cache[id];
  }else{
    cache[id] = this;
  }
}

var newitem = new item(1);
var newitem2 = new item(1);
```

This example checks the ID to see if it already exists. If it does, then it will force a return of the object that already exists, something that I actually have used in the past.

Comment: If you're implying that `newitem == newitem2` then that's absolutely not true. The only special result from your code is that `cache[1]` will equal `newitem` and not `newitem2`.

Comment: This answer is confusing, you might as well just do `return;`. Returning `cache[id]` doesn’t return anything, it just stops the exeuction as long as you use the `new` keyword when calling it.

Comment: @David: Why wouldn't they be equal? If the object has been created with that ID, the cached object is returned. *(Assuming `alreadytaken` checks the cache for that ID).* So yes, they'll be equal.

Comment: @user1689607 when using the `new` keyword, you can’t "force return" anything. You will always get the newly created object in return.

Comment: @David: That's incorrect. The entire question is based on the premise that you *can* override the return value when called with `new`. http://jsfiddle.net/UVsbK/

Comment: @user1689607 You beat me to the punch - I was just creating a fiddle, thanks.